# Using ArcGIS Pro Graticule Ticks and Labels?

Tags: arcgis-pro, grids-graticules

I want to display my Latitude ticks and labels along the left and right of my data frame and the longitudinal ticks and labels along the top and bottom of the data frame. In ArcGIS Desktop this has never been an issue. In ArcGIS Pro 2.1 it seems to want to display the longitudinal ticks and labels on every side.
The image below shows how the longitude labels are replacing some of the latitude ones when I tick 'South' as visible.

[image: graticules]

Without 'South' visible the latitude labels come back on each side but all the longitude ones are gone along the bottom.

[image: graticules 2]

Is there a way to indicate which ones I want visible on each side?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an odd glitch, as opposed to a settings issue. I've been messing around in 2.1 for the last 30 minutes trying to replicate your issue (including getting my map frame to the exact same location and extent), and I cannot get it to give me the same problem. Have you tried clearing your layout view and reloading it? If not, that may be a good first step.

Comment: No it seems to happen in any new layout I create.

Comment: Does it do it with other data, or just what you're working on there?

Comment: I've seen it in every example so far